# Using htaccess to make short link

Tags: .htaccess

I have link like this 
short.dk/testA57_Hi.89-Qwerty

I want to redirect to longdomain.dk/index.php?link=testA57_Hi.89-Qwerty

I have written the following htaccess rule
RedirectMatch ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ http://longdomain.dk/index.php?link=$1

It works fine for letters and number but how do I allow all the other characters allowed by a URL like dot, dash, underscore etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try using mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)$ /index.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note the regex change: `([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+`

which will match all letters, numbers, and underscore/dash/dot.
The reason you want to use mod_rewrite instead of mod_alias (`RedirectMatch`) is because you need the conditions so that `/index.php` doesn't end up matching your regex and cause a loop.